# Multiple Resources.Designer files in Visual Studio project

Tags: vb.net

I recently upgraded from VS 2010 to VS 2012.  On one project I am getting an error message that I can't seem to get around.  It is "module 'Resources' and module 'Resources' declared in 'C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Back Issue\BICustomer\My Project\Resources.Designer.vb', conflict in namespace 'Resources'".  When I go to the referenced 'My Project' folder, I find both a file named 'Resources.Designer.vb' and one named 'Resources1.Designer.vb', which seems to be the root of my problem.  I don't know where the second one came from--I certainly didn't create it.  I tried deleting these files one at at time, but then I just get a different error message saying that VS can't open whichever of the two I deleted.  Does anyone have an idea what I can do about this?

Comment: You have to look into the vbproj (that's the project's descriptor) file by yourself and see what references the two files. Maybe you did some operations before what you tried to undo but not every side effect was undone => some residue of some tries remained. Is it a big project? You can show the sections what reference the files. We even may need to look into the solution file, but rather the vbproj.